# cannot access Repo options in microsoft azure devops page

Tags: git, visual-studio, azure-devops, msdn

I've granted with the Visual Studio EE license and the Visual Studio Essentials subscription, however, I don't have the option in Azure DevOps to check the Repos neither I can git clone the repo. The error received says: "400: The items requested either do not exist on the server at the specified versions, or you do not have permission to access them."
The project owner has granted access but the change doesn't seem to be reflected.
What can I do?.
Thanks

Comment: There's a mixture of answers below, some of which state that this is a licensing issue and some that are categoric in stating it isn't.  For a problem we had, this _was_ a licensing issue - the user in question did not have the appropriate access level to view code.  Associating them with a valid VS Pro subscription solved the problem.

Answer (score 3):

The licences you hold have no impact on what you can access. You need to have the project administrator grant you rights to these resources in the project. I know you said they have done that, but this error would indicate that they have not.

Comment: Is there any documentation are this as I have explicitly set permission to a repo for 2 users and they both can still not see the Repos (however, others can)

Comment: @markblue777 I've just invited 2 members from the organization (but not from the dev team) and they are in Contributors group. However there is no Repos link in the Project web page for new members. And direct access to the Git repo shows 404 error in the browser. Have you managed to resolve you problem? Could you please share some workaround for this ?

Comment: I made a user project administrator days ago. He has logged in and out many times. Does not see the Repos tab on the project page. I would think that you are wrong and this is a license issue.

Comment: Also see this:https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/918777/azure-devops-users-cant-see-repos-even-though-they.html

Answer (score 3):

Go to Settings->Users, filter by "Access Level" = Stakeholder and see if your Users are there. If yes, they don't have license to access the Repo. You'll need to buy some (by clicking Summary !). After that change the access level for the users in question to Basic by clicking the 3 dots on the left in the users table.

The settings for the Organisation are available here:

```
https://dev.azure.com/<Organization_name>/_settings/users
```

Comment: Settings of what? Neither the project nor the repo has settings. Nor is there a Summary link anywhere I looked.

Comment: Project settings. I found it.

Comment: https://dev.azure.com/<Organization_name>/_settings/users

Answer (score 3):

There are several related questions here and on Microsoft forums, but none of the answers explained in clear terms what was needed to get this working. Here is what I figured out.

Azure's features and the portal UI are fluid. What works today may not work tomorrow, and vice-versa. What I am going to describe here is the behavior as of 3/18/2020.

A big part of my confusion came from the fact that user roles can be assigned at different levels, and it is entirely unclear what they are applied to. For example, I made a user project administrator and confirmed that project administrators have all the access there is to the repo, but the user still could not see the repo on the project dashboard. In the end, @Ivan's response here pointed me into the right direction. Once I figured out that on the tenant's organization settings page, the user needs an access level other than "Stakeholder", I set it to "basic" and the repo began to appear on the user's dashboard.

Intuitive, isn't it?

Comment: This is what worked for me, I changed the users access level to basic